# unable to launch hive prompt

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive, bigdata

Currently I am using hadoop version 2.6.2 and installing hive on standalone mode in ubuntu 15.10. When I am trying to launch hive shell using "hive" command, I am getting following error 
"Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported".

I am attaching the screenshot of error for full error message.

[image]

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Apached hadoop library into.bash profile

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

Fire the hive command again. It will work now.

```
# hive
```